# How to troubleshoot an unexpected Linux shutdown

Tags: linux, redhat, shutdown

I have two RHEL6.3 servers that just shutdown at the same exact time (25 seconds apart) for no apparent reason. They're on conditioned power, along with a number of other servers that didn't shut down, so it can't be the power. The room is properly chilled and them both shutting off at the exact same time due to temperature seems unlikely.

At the time of shutdown, both servers have the following in their /var/log/secure. I don't know what it means but found it peculiar.

```
Apr 10:42:52 localhost polkitd(authority=local): Unregistered Authentication Agent for session /org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Session1 (system bus name :1.25, object path /org/gnome/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
```

In /var/log/messages, both systems have what seems like they received a clean shutdown request

```
Apr 10 10:42:52 localhost init: tty (/dev/tty2) main process (6183) killed by TERM signal
Apr 10 10:42:52 localhost init: tty (/dev/tty3) main process (6186) killed by TERM signal
Apr 10 10:42:52 localhost init: tty (/dev/tty4) main process (6188) killed by TERM signal
Apr 10 10:42:52 localhost init: tty (/dev/tty5) main process (6190) killed by TERM signal
Apr 10 10:42:52 localhost init: tty (/dev/tty6) main process (6192) killed by TERM signal
```

So I checked last to see if anyone logged in to do that and both have this entry with no one logging in prior for days.

```
reboot     system boot   2.6.32-279.el6.x Thu Apr 10 10:42 - 10:42  (00:00)
```

So if no one logged in to shut it down and I had two guys that were there witness the servers shutdown and they confirmed no one touched either of the servers, what else could cause this shutdown? Where else should I look for clues?

Comment: do you have system accounting turned on?

Comment: AFAIK, last uses the system accounting functionality by parsing wtmp, if that's what you're talking about. And my last shows a system reboot at the exact time with the only other login being from yesterday and that session lasting only a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is a kernel oops (kernel panic), you need to capture the output from the server console to understand what exactly happened.
You can do so using:

- Physical access to console, typically you'd need to take a picture of the screen to capture the panic (least reliable way to capture)
- Remote IP KVM (make a screenshot)
- Serial console (log console output via *serial cable* from problem computer to another) http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/centos-rhel-6-install-serial-console/
- Network console (log console output to another server in your network) https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Netconsole

Things to double check on all servers to be successful:

- Check kernel.panic option in /etc/sysrq.conf, that controls the timeout after which Linux will reboot after kernel panic
- Check the kernel log level via kernel.printk in /etc/sysrq.conf, recommended with more debug would be: `echo 'kernel.printk = 8 4 1 7' >> /etc/sysctl.conf`